# Lambda Capture and Memory Management

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, lambda

When I capture an object by reference in a C++11 lambda, let the object go out of scope, and then execute the lambda, it still has access to the object. When I execute the following code, the lambda call can still access the object, although the destructor has already been called! Can someone explain why this works and why I don't get a runtime error?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    int health = 5;
    MyClass() {std::cout << "MyClass created!\n";}
    ~MyClass() {std::cout << "MyClass destroyed!\n";}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::function<bool (int)> checkHealth;
    if(true) {
        MyClass myVanishingObject;
        checkHealth = [&myVanishingObject] (int minimumHealth) -> bool {
            std::cout << myVanishingObject.health << std::endl;
            return myVanishingObject.health >= minimumHealth;
        };
    } // myVanishingObject goes out of scope

    // let's do something with the callback to test if myVanishingObject still exists.
    if(checkHealth(4)) {
        std::cout << "has enough health\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "doesn't have enough health\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
MyClass created!
MyClass destroyed!
5
has enough health
```

Comment: I suspect that this is undefined behavior, and in this case that undefined behavior just happens to be "the object appears to be alive and well."

Comment: Undefined behaviour. See http://c-faq.com/ansi/experiment.html

Comment: If you run this through a memory leak analyzer (such as Valgrind), it'll (hopefully) report that you are accessing a dead object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [the cppreference.com website's documentation of lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

> **Dangling references**
>
> If an entity is captured by reference, implicitly or explicitly, and the function call operator of the closure object is invoked after the entity's lifetime has ended, undefined behavior occurs. The C++ closures do not extend the lifetimes of the captured references.

In other words, the fact that you have captured the object by reference and then let the object's lifetime ends means that invoking the lambda causes undefined behavior.  Since one possible way that UB might work is "the object appears to be alive and well even though the object is dead," I suspect that you are seeing undefined behavior manifesting itself as nothing appearing to have gone wrong.

I suspect this would be the case if the compiler allocated a unique stack location to the temporary variable.  This would mean that after the lifetime of the object ends, before `main` returns, the memory wouldn't be touched by anything.  Accordingly, you'd see the variable holding the value `5` just as before, since nothing else is writing on top of it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So what would be a good way to handle this? My suggestion is to create a shared_ptr to myVanishingObject (instead of the instance on the stack), and capture that shared_ptr by value. What do you think?

Comment: @basteln- That makes perfect sense - you want the object to persist beyond the scope in which it's created, so it's reasonable to heap-allocate it and use a `shared_ptr` to handle the memory management.  Just make sure to capture the pointer by value!

Comment: Ok, your answer is good but how can we solve this problem? In Obj-C and Swift object captured by lambdas are retained (reference counter is incremented) and released after lambda is released